# Install XAMP with PHP switch

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I am looking to download WAMP a friend of mine said with WAMP you can switch PHP versions. I went to the WAMP download page `http://www.wampserver.com/en/` and clicked on PHP addons and there is a list of PHP versions but it will only let me select one. By downloading WAMP this way, Am I just selecting which PHP version I want as the extra PHP version to switch too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically.

From their site:

> "You will then be able to switch from one release to another from the
>   WampServer menu."

Answer (score 0):

Download one of the WAMP versions lets say wampserver 2.2 with whatever version of APache/MySQL/PHP that contains.

Install that.

Then you can add PHP versions using the ADDON of whatever PHP version you want to be using.
Theere is an option on the wampmanager -> PHP -> Version - More
that will take you to the ADDONS automatically.